# Creating an edmx out of DLL

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have this project of mine that is a bit confusing to me. I was provided with the SQL script for the database together with a Model.dll (I am assuming this is an entity model). Now, I know how to create an edmx using the provided sql script by importing it as ADO.NET Entity Model. What I don't understand is that, if I'll do it that way then the model.dll that was will be irrelevant as it will simply create the same model. Is this right?

I also have another question, is it possible to create an edmx model using that dll (model.dll) that was provided?

Comment: Please go through this https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/815065/what-is-a-dll for more info on dll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely the script is to create the database, and you can just reference the dll to connect or work with that database. So either you create your own edmx/mapping classes or use the provided .dll (if it is what you think it is.)

If you really want to know what is inside this dll, i suggest to open it using ILSPY, which will allow you to browse the various methods and contents easily.

(https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/ilspy/9mxfbkfvsq13?activetab=pivot:overviewtab)

Comment: Yes, the provided dll was indeed the edmx. If it's not too much to ask, can you explain a little bit on how do I reference the dll to connect to the database? Or a site reference that I can read would be nice. I actually was searching for that as well but couldnt find an answer. What I tried so far was referencing the dll file using Ado.NET Entity Model import wizard in VS. But when I try to select the file, it can only detect MS SQL dbo files.

Comment: You can add the .dll file as a reference to the project in Visual Studio.
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1e050f/creating-and-using-dll-class-library-in-C-Sharp/

Scroll down to "Using DLL File". It comes down to: "Right-click on the project and then click on "Add reference"." Then select the file you want (maybe copy it to the project directory first) and click OK. You should be able to use it in code then, providing you know the namespace (most likely name of the dll).